# Rechtschreibung: "Gibt's das auch {im Heiß · in heiß}"?

Tags: spelling

Ich habe Folgendes in einer Sendung gehört:

Einem Typen wird (allem Anschein nach) *kalter* Kaffee eingeschenkt, worauf er

> Gibt's das auch `im heiß`? (oder so in der Art)

antwortet.

Wie schreibt man das richtig:

- *in* oder *im*?
- muss *heiß* großgeschrieben werden?

Die Handlung findet in Köln statt.

Comment: Bist Du Dir sicher, das "im" gehört zu haben? Ohne wäre es eine einfache Verkürzung: "Gibt es auch heißen (Kaffee)?"

Comment: So sicher bin ich nicht (*Gibt's auch den heiß* könnte auch sein, aber da höre ich kein *e* sondern *i*). Steht auf der [ADR-Seite](http://www.daserste.de/unterhaltung/krimi/tatort/videos/freddy-tanzt-video-tgl-ab-20-uhr-100.html) Die genaue Zeit, 01:02:33, kann ich leider nicht verlinken.

Comment: „Gibt's den auch in heiß?“

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Du warst eine halbe Minute schneller als ich. Ich meine "das" statt "den" gehört zu haben, aber das kommt auf's selbe raus. Ich glaube, Du kannst das als Antwort schreiben.

Comment: @Matthias, ich habe nicht noch einmal nachgehört, ich habe vorhin den Tatort gesehen. Es ist also gut möglich, dass ein Wort falsch ist. Du kannst das gerne erklären.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Der Mann sagt

> Gibt's das [oder: den] auch *in Heiß*?

Die Konstruktion *in + Adjektiv* wird (meist in dieser Weise, also "Gibt's ...") umgangssprachlich verwendet, um auszudrücken, dass an einem Gegenstand eine konkrete Eigenschaft verändert werden sollte. Der Mann will also einen heißen Kaffee, keinen kalten oder lauwarmen.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es sich um eine (standardsprachlich eigentlich falsche) Verallgemeinerung von *in + Farbe* handelt. Wenn man Kleidungsstücke kauft und z.B. eine passende Hose gefunden hat, die nur leider schwarz ist statt wie gewünscht blau, so kann man den Verkäufer fragen: "Gibt's die auch in Blau?"

Die Großschreibung der Adjektive in dieser Verwendung ergibt sich aus dem substantivischen Gebrauch. Der Duden erklärt das in [Regel 72](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#K72).